# How can I detect, when the connection of the client gets interrupted in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node.js-Server with a socket.io-connection to a browser-client. sometimes the connection gets interrupted, for example, when I need to restart the server. When that happens, how can the client know this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example on how you can achieve that on the client side:

```
var chat = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/chat');
chat.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected to the chat!');
});
chat.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('Disconnected from the chat!');
});
```

As you can see, you keep the connection variable and you use connection_variable.on('disconnect', callback_function_here)

Comment: Thank you, easier that I thought :)